# On power of $P/poly$

Tags: complexity-theory, circuits

**(1)** We know that $EXP ⊄ P/poly ⇒ BPP$ is in $SUBEXP$. Does $SUBEXP ⊄ P/poly$ mean $P=BPP$ or anything close?

**(2)** We know that if $NP$ is in $P/poly$ then $PH$ collapses to second level. What is the consequence if $\oplus P$ is in $P/poly$?

Comment: Polynomials grow more slowly than 2^n, so for sufficiently large n, there will be more possible length-n queries than the length of the advice. ​ For n that's _not_ large enough, the NP machine can just have part of the language hard-coded. ​ For large-enough n, the advice can be the oracle's outputs for the n-bit encodings of the polynomially-many smallest nonnegative integers. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Does that make it clear? ​ In any case, the "good collapse" I mentioned, which follows from [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0890540105000155), is that ​ coNP $\subseteq$ NP/poly ​ implies ​ PH collapses to [S$_2\hspace{-0.02 in}$](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:S#s2p)P$^{NP}$. ​ ​ ​ (Directly from the definitions, one gets ​ (S$_2\hspace{-0.02 in}$P)$^{NP}$ = S$_2\hspace{-0.05 in}\left(\hspace{-0.02 in}P^{\hspace{.02 in}NP}\hspace{-0.02 in}\right)$ , ​ so my previous sentence is unambiguous.) ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39198/discussion-on-question-by-turbo-on-power-of-p-poly).

Comment: Please use the chatroom Gilles created, rather than discussing the question in the comments here.  Thank you.

Comment: @D.W why do you have to delete comment?